# Using a query string on my master page markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I need to supply a variable that I have in a query string to tell which push pins to draw on my map. Currently I have to hard code the beer name as I have done with "Stella" in the if statement. Is there a way that I can refer to my query string (beerName=Stella) to change this instead. This is all on the master page btw. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


          $.ajax({
              url: "Handler2.ashx",
              type: "post",
              data: { "Action": "SearchByLocation" },
              success: function (data) {
                  for (var i = 0; data.Locations.length - 1; i++) {
                      var pushPin2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data.Locations[i].Latitude, data.Locations[i].Longitude), null);
                      $("#newdiv li").append("<li><a href='" + "Main.aspx?beerName=" + data.Locations[i].beerName + "'>" + data.Locations[i].beerName + "</a></li>")
                      collectionInMemory = data;
                      if (data.Locations[i].beerName == "Stella") {
                          map.entities.push(pushPin2);

                      }

                  }


                 for (var j = 0; j < collectionInMemory.Locations.length - 1; j++) {
                     if(collectionInMemory.Locations[j].BeerName = "Stella") alert("datada");
                  }
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("failure");
                  $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
              }

          });
```

Comment: Use the [jQuery Url Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline ASP.NET snippet like so, and it will render the query string variable

```
  if (data.Locations[i].beerName == <%= Request.QueryString("beerName") %>) {
      map.entities.push(pushPin2);
      }
```